# python: how to create submatrices? Numpy

Tags: python, matrix

I have a matrix 1500X2, and I have to create 10 submatrices of 150 rows. How can i do this without `for` loop. I need a function, because with the [:] is too slow and complicated

Comment: Why not show a [mcve] and some benchmarks that show what is slow?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [numpy.take](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) function to select a range of rows of your matrix. You can pass the indices you want to select and the axis over which you want to select your items.

```
import numpy as np

indices = list(range(0,3))

array = np.random.rand(5,2)
print(array)

res = np.take(array, indices, 0)
print(res)
```

You get something like this:

```
[[0.63680493 0.27066094]
 [0.71182288 0.48258969]
 [0.61321531 0.02215374]
 [0.98148503 0.5669895 ]
 [0.42720908 0.57326236]]

[[0.63680493 0.27066094]
 [0.71182288 0.48258969]
 [0.61321531 0.02215374]]
```